# Jelastic custom run command

Tags: docker, jelastic, osrm

I'm trying to install OSRM on Jelastic docker container.

This is the guide for running it on a local docker: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend, it works to perfection.

Now I want to run it on a Jelastic container, but I dont know how to run custom RUN commands.

For example:

```
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf
```

That code runs fine in my local windows docker, but how do I tell jelastic to run the container with custom arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I got it...

Actually those commands can be run directly from BASH.

So the correct way to solve this is to create an SH file in your container and make it run at startup.

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: This article might be also useful https://jelastic.com/blog/container-types/.